# How to find all the #if conditions that surround a given line of C++ code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, c-preprocessor, conditional-compilation

I'm trying to untangle some code I didn't write. There are a lot of #if statements nested throughout this long file. I'd like a way to quickly identify all the #if statements that surround a given piece of code. Trying to search the Web for "#if" is hard since that either gets hashtags or ignores the punctuation, and "conditional preprocessor directives" didn't turn up anything other than a description of what they are.

- Are there any commandline tools that already exist to find all the #ifs affecting a given line?
- I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Pro. Are there any extensions that do that?

Comment: What you might look for is an auto-formatter that can parse `#if` directives and indent the code accordingly. That would help you to see the flow, and make the code more readable while you were at it.

Comment: @CodyGray - It helps, but it rarely leaves the code in a way that you'd want it permanantaly.  #ifs often show up in the middle of blocks, and you don't really want that indented again permanantly.  While trying to figure out the preprocessor flow it helps, though.

Comment: Do you need to include included headers in the analysis? I.e. is it OK to assume that the `#if` and `#endif` are on .c file level? I.e. can we assume that no `#if` will be opended and not closed in a header?

Comment: Are you thinking of "a given piece of code" as in "a few specific lines" for which you want the surrounding prepro constructs? Or is it more like a special way of preprocessing whole files? Do it once and then be able to read the complete code, while having convenient access to the desired info. Phrased differently, how would a parser identify the "given piece of code" ?

Comment: Proposal for representation: Insert comment lines with all currently active preprocessor constructs before each new prepro construct. Would that be helpful?

Comment: Could you make a sample input for playing with? Something showing all cases you are interested in.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes, assume all #if/#else/#endif are at the same level. Also, yes, adding comments is my current strategy. I'm not interested in solutions where I'm mapping out the file. I am seeking automation: from top of file to current line, which #ifs had to be true or false to make the current line active.

Comment: With that it sounds like self-made solution in awk or perl is possible (sed for masochists or brain joggers). Just one info I still miss: How would such a parser know the "current line"? Could you e.g. provide the line number as parameter to that parser? Otherwise it sounds like you could accept the proposed representation, inserted comment lines at each `#if`. You (human eye) could look backwards from current line to the first (or last) `#if` you find before. I might try to implement on the weekend, but I really want a sample input. Use any level of complicated constructs you like.

Comment: Just to clarify: "masochists or brain joggers" I consider no insult to anybody, at least it is not meant to be one. I myself love trying to solve things in sed. And "brain jogger" might be no actual English expression; it could be a typical "I think this is English" mistake by me and my fellows in language. ;-)

Comment: On the topic of internet-searching for programming keywords: Did you try looking for "preprocessor if"? Also, I find searching non-English pages for quasi-English keywords helpful; if they mention "if" then it is usually programming related. This assumes that you have a second language skill of course. Your participation in language related stackexchange might indicate that.

Answer (score 1):

Not a proper answer but you can use sublime text editor.

In sublime you can select `#if`by pressing `ctrl + D`one by one.

and if you want to find all press `ctrl + f` and type #if it will select all.

> it want take too long to download it. you can download it from [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/3). it is only about 8 mb in windows.